# How to improve the Maintainability Index of the Plato report

Tags: angularjs, plato

I have generated the Plato report for the AngularJS code and now I want to know how I can improve the Maintainability Index.
Lint errors improvement does not improve the Maintainability Index.
Any refernce links, very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this site,](http://jscomplexity.org/complexity) which gives a formula for the Oman/Hagemeister Maintainability Index.

> Values are on a logarithmic scale ranging from negative infinity up to 171, with greater numbers indicating a higher level of maintainability. In their original paper, Oman and Hagemeister identified 65 as the threshold value below which a program should be considered difficult to maintain.
>
> DEPENDENCIES
>   A list of dependencies from calls to CommonJS and AMD require. Analysed statically from the function signature, so no accounting is made for dynamic calls where a variable or function is obscuring the nature of the dependency. Fewer is better.
>
> FIRST-ORDER DENSITY
>   The percentage of all possible internal dependencies that are actually realised in the project. Lower is better.
>
> CHANGE COST
>   The percentage of modules affected, on average, when one module in the project is changed. Lower is better.
>
> CORE SIZE
>   The percentage of modules that are both widely depended on and themselves depend on other modules. Lower is better.

I can't find whether [Plato](https://github.com/es-analysis/plato) uses this or not, but hopefully this will help you understand what goes into metrics like this.